# A question about the Symetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is my question:
Prove that there is no subgroup with size 6 in the symmetric group $A_4$.

What i thought is that $A_4$ has all the 2,4 circles,a subgroup with order 6 must be cyclic so there is no element in $A_6$ with order 6 so there is no subgroup with size 6.

I want to be sure that I am right,

thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered on our site many times. For example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150628/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94137/11619). Several good (and some possibly not so good) answeres there.